# how do I pin a program to the taskbar with powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to pin several programs to the taskbar with the help of a Powershell Script

I tried most methods shared here but it didn't work for Windows 10

Comment: See also: [Pin your app to the taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/pin-to-taskbar)

Comment: `get-command -noun startlayout`  Although you have to edit the xml.  This question is already answered on another closed question?

Answer (score 0):

computer management. Path: %windir%\system32\compmgmt.msc

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I need code that can do this job not path

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: @latest. SO, and sites like these are not free script-writing services. We are here to help folks who have code that is not working. You are not showing any code. BTW, There are many samples all over the web and on Youtube showing you how to do this with code. Try and search for that first, then makes some attempts and get back to use if it is not working.